# How do you manage User-Agent strings for a Kivy Application?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm building an application in a python library called Kivy. My app requires the use of an API, and that API needs a user-agent string to identify the app and user. I'm not too knowledgable when it comes to user-agent strings, but I'm pretty sure they require information about the device the app is running on. If Kivy apps can be exported onto multiple different platforms, is there a way to grab information about the device it's being used on so that it can create a sensible user-agent string?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [user-agent header docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).
Values are mostly tied to the web browser that made the request.

That doesn't have to be the rule and you can construct your own:
`User-Agent: KivyAppName/AppVersion`

So if you are using http client like `requests`, your code would be:

```py
import requests

url = "url-to-your-api_endpoint"
headers = {"User-Agent": "KivyAppName/AppVersion"}
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

If your API only allows web browser agents, you can use the [fake-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) package to generate one for you.